# Groovy compare two lists to find lists with common elements

Tags: groovy, compare

How do I compare two lists in groovy

```
[N1OB] == [ABCD9, ABCD8, ABCD7] -> should return false

[ABCD1, ABCD1, ABCD1, ABCD1] == [ABCD9, ABCD8, ABCD7] -> should return false

[ABCD1, ABCD1, ABCD1, ABCD1] == [ABCD9, ABCD8, ABCD1] -> should return true
```

is there any groovy function there to do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solved by

```
List newList = ["ABCD9", "ABCD8", "ABCD7"]
List oldList = ["dfgdfg"]

if(newList.intersect(oldList))
println("difference->")
```

Think it is correct, can someone suggest

Comment: intersect is the way to go for your goal.  your question should have reflected this a little more...

Comment: Keep in mind here that intersect **does not** return a boolean but the intersection of two lists. In your logic, it is Groovy Truth which kicks in to validate that there is at least on intersection. Benefit:- If required, you can get the common elements as `def commonItems = newList.intersect(oldList)`. :) If you just need to check with a boolean you can also use `!newList.disjoint(oldList)`. `disjoint()` returns a boolean.

Comment: @dmahapatro, I didn't got your point clearly, I guess `intersection + groovy truth` is working fine for me

Answer (score 1):

`disjoint()` returns `false` if any element in list one is in list two. If you add negation you will have:

```
!(['N1OB'].disjoint(['ABCD9', 'ABCD8', 'ABCD7']))  // false

!(['ABCD1', 'ABCD1', 'ABCD1', 'ABCD1'].disjoint(['ABCD9', 'ABCD8', 'ABCD7']))  // false

!(['ABCD1', 'ABCD1', 'ABCD1', 'ABCD1'].disjoint(['ABCD9', 'ABCD8', 'ABCD1']) )  // true
```